# How to show Slider Label without division in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, slider

Hey I want to show label in slider without division parameter in flutter. As I add the division parameter it will show label.

```
 Slider(
        label: "Power: ",
          min: 0,
          max: 9,
          value: _value,
          onChanged: (double newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _value = newValue;
            });
          },
        )
```

More Clarification :

Why I needed the slider without divider.
because from slider i got the price of property of user specific to its own property, So, I don't use divider because it will opt out this option from user.

Comment: Can I know why you are not willing to use the divider?

Comment: @GHPrakash because from slider i got the price of property of user specific to its own property, So, I don't use divider because it will opt out this option from user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `ShowValueIndicator.always` in your `ThemeData` as follows:

```
ThemeData(
  sliderTheme: SliderThemeData(
    showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always,
  )
)
```

Check docs for more details: [ShowValueIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ShowValueIndicator.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it works for me.
You can use the variable 'dividers' and choose as many fractions as you want, for instance 1000. Here some examples:

With divisions: 100

```
Slider(
  value: _sliderValue,
  max: 100,
  min: 0,
  divisions: 100,  // it doesn't print 100 dots, don't worry
  label: _sliderValue.toStringAsFixed(0),  
  // in label, "toStringAsFixed()" determine the amount of decimals to show in string format
  onChanged: (double newValue){
    setState(() {
      _sliderValue = newValue;
    });
  }
)
```

[image slider 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJamt.jpg)

[image slider 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CgdQ.jpg)

With divisions: 1000

```
Slider(
  value: _sliderValue,
  max: 100,
  min: 0,
  divisions: 1000,  // it doesn't print 1000 dots, don't worry
  label: _sliderValue.toStringAsFixed(2),  
  // in label, "toStringAsFixed()" determine the amount of decimals to show in string format
  onChanged: (double newValue){
    setState(() {
      _sliderValue = newValue;
    });
  }
)
```

[image slider 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtxaj.jpg)

[image slider 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQTCE.jpg)

With divisions: 10000

```
Slider(
  value: _sliderValue,
  max: 100,
  min: 0,
  divisions: 10000,  // it doesn't print 10000 dots, don't worry
  label: _sliderValue.toStringAsFixed(2),  
  // in label, "toStringAsFixed()" determine the amount of decimals to show in string format
  onChanged: (double newValue){
    setState(() {
      _sliderValue = newValue;
    });
  }
)
```

[image slider 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSWgy.jpg)

[image slider 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9LH5.jpg)

I hope it will help you.